# Haskell : Show instance Ambiguity

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a show instance to display well formed formula but after miming whole syntax I am still facing the same error as below.

```
Hugs> :load "C:\\Users\\Devil\\Desktop\\CASESTUDY1.hs"
ERROR file:.\CASESTUDY1.hs:15 - Ambiguous variable occurrence "show"
*** Could refer to: CASESTUDY1.show Hugs.Prelude.show
```

Below is the content of my .hs file include data type and related show instance .

```
module CASESTUDY1

where 

data Wff =   VAR String 
            | NEG Wff
            | AND Wff Wff 
            | OR Wff Wff
            | IMPL Wff Wff

instance Show Wff where
show (VAR x) = x
show (NEG x) = "~" ++ show(x)
show (AND x y) = "(" ++ show(x) ++ "^" ++ show(y) ++ ")"
show (OR x y) = "(" ++ show(x) ++ "v" ++ show(y) ++ ")"
show (IMPL x y) = "(" ++ show(x) ++ "-->" ++ show(y) ++ ")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In haskell, whitespace is important. You need to indent the `show`'s that belong to your instance of `Show`.

```
instance Show Wff where
   show (VAR x)     = show x
   show (NEG x)     = "~" ++ show x
   show (AND x y)   = "(" ++ show x ++ "^" ++ show y ++ ")"
   show (OR x y)    = "(" ++ show x ++ "v" ++ show y ++ ")"
   show (IMPL x y)  = "(" ++ show x ++ "-->" ++ show y ++ ")"
```

Also, you do not need parenthesis to pass the parameters to show. `show(x)` should be `show x`.

---

If you are learning haskell I recommend these exceptional resources:

- [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com)
- [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dacto, It's been so long since I touched haskell.. thank u very very much ...